# Can't infer generic type on static function with completion block

Tags: swift, generics

I have a static function that uses generics, but I can't get it to infer the generic type when it's called. The function:

```
static func getDocument<T: JSONDecodable>(_ document: String, fromCollection collection: FirebaseStorage.FirestoreCollections, completion: @escaping (_ decodedDoc: T?, _ error: Error?) -> ()) {
    let docRef = firestore.collection(collection.rawValue).document(document)
    docRef.getDocument { documentSnapshot, error in
        guard error == nil,
            let docData = documentSnapshot?.data(),
            let decodedDoc = T(json: docData) else {
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }
        completion(decodedDoc, nil)
    }
}
```

Called using:

```
FirebaseClient.getDocument(
    id,
    fromCollection: FirebaseStorage.FirestoreCollections.users) { (profile, error) in

}
```

This gives the error: `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred`. How can I make the generic part of the function work?

Comment: What type _is_ `profile` meant to be? If I can't infer it looking at your code then nor can Swift :)

Comment: @KaneCheshire Good point! Basically I wanted to set it as something that conforms to the protocol of `JSONDecodable`. But if I write `FirebaseClient.getDocument<ProfileJSONModel>(...)` for example it complains that the type can't be set directly.

Comment: You will need to provide the data type for `profile`.

Comment: @Samah But where do I provide that? The function is `Void` so I can't make it infer the type by assigning it to a variable

Comment: When you call `getDocument`, provide the expected data type for `profile` in the closure.  There needs to be somewhere in the calling code that lets the Swift compiler know which generic arguments the function should expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FirebaseClient.getDocument(
    id,
    fromCollection: FirebaseStorage.FirestoreCollections.users) { (profile: ProfileType?, error) in

}
```

You'll need to let Swift know what type `profile` is where I've added `ProfileType`. That should do it!

Answer (score 1):

Kane's answer is good, but a more flexible approach is to pass the type directly. For example, this makes it possible to have an optional completion handler, or to ignore the parameter with `_` if you don't care about it. (That said, this approach is a little longer to type, so sometimes Kane's way is better.)

```
static func getDocument<T: JSONDecodable>(_ document: String,
                                          ofType: T.Type,
                                          completion: @escaping (_ decodedDoc: T?, _ error: Error?) -> ())
```

This makes everything explicit. You call it this way:

```
FirebaseClient.getDocument(id, ofType: ProfileType.self) { (profile, error) in ... }
```

Note that there's no need to use the `ofType` parameter for anything. It's just there to specialize the generic.

This is pretty close to how `Decodable` works, and is applicable to a lot of problems. But Kane's solution is also handy at times if it's more convenient.